# Distinct repeated timeouts for UIView.animate

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uikit

The UIKit's UIView.animate() method appears to be useful when implementing many animations. However, I recently ran into a problem while implementing a series of repeated animations with different timeouts.

Suppose, we have a list of images `let images: [UIImage]` and an image view `@IBOutlet weak var presentingImageView: UIImageView!`. We want to make it change its image every 3.0 seconds, for that case we would write the following code:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3.0, repeats: true) { _ in
    self.index += 1
}

UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0,
               delay: 0.1,
               options: .repeat,
               animations: { 
                   self.presentingImageView.image = images[index]
               })
```

And it would work, but what if we also have an array of durations `let durations: [TimeInterval]` and we want to change images every `duration[index]` seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Then nest them and remove `repeat`

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3.0, repeats: true) { _ in
    self.index += 1
    guard self.duration.count > index, self.images.count > index else { return }
    UIView.animate(withDuration:self.duration[index],
           delay: 0.1,
           options: .repeat,  
    animations: { 
            self.presentingImageView.image = self.images[index]
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of timer, you can call 'changeImage' function every 'durations[Index]'.

```
func changeImage() {
    let duration = durations[index]
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
                   delay: 0.1,
                   options: .repeat,
                   animations: {
                    self.presentingImageView.image = self.images[self.index]
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + duration) {
                        self.changeImage()
                    }
    })
}
```